# Parity of 4×4 normal magic squares

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I'm writing a program that given an integer n returns all normal magic squares of size n × n. Fiddling around with it a little I started to notice that if n equals 4, every square I saw followed this rule: each row and column must have exactly 2 odd and 2 even numbers. I have no idea why it can't be 4 of one or 4 of the other, but I changed the algorithm to take that into account and it still showed the same results, while being way faster.I think this is kind of fascinating, and out of curiosity I've been trying to prove why it works like this, but I have been struggling with it. I've been trying to do proof by contradiction, but this is all I have this far:

Suppose we have 4 even numbers arranged in any of the rows. A normal 4×4 magic square has 8 even integers, so that means we need to add 4 more. Its magic number is 34, so there should be one in each column in order to make an even sum possible. We can't place them all in the same row, because the sum of every positive integer between 1 and 16 is 72 and the other complete row of even numbers already sums 34, which means this should add up to 38. There can't be only one of them in any of the rows, because again that would not add to 34.

My problem is that I can't justify why there can't be 2 in one row, 2 in another and only odd numbers in the last row. I know it's not possible because my program works either way,  but I haven't been able to come up with an explanation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may be that there is no explanation more elegant than an exhaustive case analysis which generates all 4x4 magic squares.

Comment: Another fascinating thing is that all 4x4 magic squares are even permutations of [1, 2, 3, ... , 16].

Comment: What does "normal" mean (in the context of magic squares)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was told it meant that they had every integer between 1 and n^2, once

Comment: In a deleted answer, user Antoine Labelle tried to show there was no solution modulo $4$ (with the odd-even distribution OP asks about), but @PeterTaylor produced counterexamples (also modulo $8$). However, Peter's counterexamples don't satisfy the magic square condition on the diagonals. Maybe Labelle's argument can be patched by considering the diagonals?